# How do I know which C++ standard version I should use to build which version of Boost?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, build, configuration

When you download the Boost sources, there's no indication of which C++ language standard version you should be using to build it. But - clearly there's no auto-selection, since if you don't set, say, at least `--std=c++11`  then some configuration checks for C++11 features fail. So it's up to you, the builder, to set that.

But - how do I know which C++ standard version to use for which Boost version? Is there like a table somewhere?

Specifically, I just built Boost 1.62.0 with --std=c++14 and got innumerable warnings about the use of `sts::auto_ptr` which is deprecated. So, should I have stuck with C++11? How can I tell?

Comment: It's a bad sign that boost still fails to compile w/o warnings for the 2014 standard.

Comment: @Walter: In fairness though, it's not the latest version (which is 1.63.0 by now).

Comment: You should choose the same version as for your source code. BOOST is mostly header files, so you will compile it with your choice of C++ anyway. Its worth mentioning that C++ is backward compatible so C++14 version will compile C++98 with no problem, maybe with some depracation errors.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, some boost developers haven't updated their implementation with the newest standards (even C++11) with the problems that you present. 
There is a [boost_config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html) set of macros that can be used for keeping up with compatibility.

But usually the problem with the compilers is using an older one not newer.

Comment: These macros are useful for Boost library authors; you're not really answering *my* question...

Answer (score -1):

Warnings are no errors. C++14 supports std::auto_ptr with no restrictions. So you can use C++14, but you should not use std::auto_ptr in your new code. You should also not use std::auto_ptr with C++11.
EDIT: Since the OP didn't get the glue. If both support it, it makes no difference and he can use which one he likes.

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer to my question.

Comment: OK, to say more simple: You can use both.

Comment: Warnings are given for a good reason. They normally point to a potential problem and good code should compile w/o any warnings. Having said that, some warnings can be safely ignored by experienced programmers. IMHO in this case the offending code should be marked (using the usual `#pragma` instructions) for ignoring the corresponding compiler flag. However, boost should not use `std::auto_ptr` if C++14 is used.

Comment: @user6556709 I disagree. Why otherwise would the compiler builders bother to issue a warning, if not for a good reason? Of course, the compiler may not be able to distinguish whether a certain situation is dangerous, but at least is can (and hence should/must) warn about *potential danger*.

Comment: @Walter 1. It was a joke. 2. I've seen many warnings, which simply results from errors in the compiler. The pattern matching for the warnings are not perfect. 3. You're right the compiler is not clever enough to get the context of a statement always correct.

Answer (score -1):

Dont know about the Boost but you can get the c++ version from any c++ compiler like this -

```
 if( __cplusplus == 201103L ) std::cout << "C++11 " ;
 if( __cplusplus == 199711L ) std::cout << "C++98 " ;
   //... like this
```

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: The OP knows that. The question was which C++ standard, i.e. which compiler option (`-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`) to use when building boost (i.e. compiling the boost source files to generate the boost library).